# Trouble with findViewById() ... returns NULL when I don't think it should

Tags: android

This is an Android resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:paddingRight="20dip" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/pt_name_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/pt_dob_view"/>

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/pt_mrun_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the corresponding class within the Android application:

```
public class PatientViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.patient_view);

        // ... some irrelevant code ... 

        final TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pt_name_view);
        nameView.setText(pt.getSurname().toUpperCase() + ", " + pt.getGivenNames() );

        // ... some more irrelevant code ...

}
```

This code worked fine until recently.  Now suddenly nameView is NULL when the code is run despite the fact that neither file has been altered.

Comment: I cleaned the project and the problem went away.  Still don't know why it happened in the first place, though.

Comment: Bet you're using Eclipse, it tends to mess resource compilcation sometimes. When you see strange things going on, firstly try to clean the project. Or you could switch to Intellij IDEA, it doesn't have such issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make a little change to resources (even add a space, a character, moving file, add files...), your project compilation might go rogue sometimes.

Just keep in mind, nothing is perfect and have a good practice. You've learned a lesson: `always save & clean project before running`.